# php connect to amazon simple db

Tags: php, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to figure out how to connect to amazon simple db and retrieve data with a select statement. The domain is already set up. It seems like the following should work, but when I try it, I have no success. I don't get any error, my website just goes blank. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;

// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
'key'    => 'mykey',
'secret' => 'mysecret',

));

$result = $s3Client->select(array(
'SelectExpression' => "select * from mydomain"
));

?>
```

Comment: You don't output anything here.  print_r($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client` provides the client for accessing the `Amazon S3` web service. You need `com.amazonaws.services.simpledb.AmazonSimpleDBClient` to connect with `Amazon SimpleDB`.

[Link of javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpledb/AmazonSimpleDBClient.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are not outputting your `$result` variable, so that might be the issue.. ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Outputting the result doesn't help, because the query itself is causing the error. Anytime I try to access the $s3Client variable at all the website goes blank including if I output the result.

Comment: Try catching the error using `try { $result = $s3Client... } catch(Exception $e) { echo $e->getMessage(); }`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! This was the exception "Command was not found matching Select"

Comment: I have no experience in using S3Client, so I can't offer anymore help than this link [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/quick-start.html)